# Create and write dynamically into multiple files in python

Tags: python, xml, file

I have the following snippet where I am writing the updated values of the variables into output.xml file but i want to be able to create as many xml files as the number of iterations in the for loop. Is there a way where I can try to give the output file name with the iter value? Like `Output1.xml, Output2.xml` and so on?

```
 for child in root.iter('Traces'):
    child.find('D')
    child.find('TS')
    child.find('TW')
    for i in frange(3,12.75,0.25):
        child.set('TS',str(i))
        child.set('TW',str(i))
        #child.set('D',str(j))
        tree.write('C:\Users\Aravind_Sampathkumar\Desktop\IMLC\BO\Output.xml')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a counter for different files.

```
fileCount = 1 

for child in root.iter('Traces'):
    child.find('D')
    child.find('TS')
    child.find('TW')
    for i in frange(3,12.75,0.25):
        child.set('TS',str(i))
        child.set('TW',str(i))
        #child.set('D',str(j))
        tree.write('C:\Users\Aravind_Sampathkumar\Desktop\IMLC\BO\Output{}.xml'.format(fileCount))
        fileCount += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for child in root.iter('Traces'):
    child.find('D')
    child.find('TS')
    child.find('TW')
    count = 1
    for i in frange(3,12.75,0.25):
        child.set('TS',str(i))
        child.set('TW',str(i))
        #child.set('D',str(j))
        tree.write('C:\Users\Aravind_Sampathkumar\Desktop\IMLC\BO\Output{0}.xml'.format(count))
        count += 1
```